# Is there a way in Sublime text 3 to auto add the format for language after selecting it from syntax?

Tags: html, syntax, format, sublimetext3

I am looking for a way, for Sublime Text, to add the "necessary" format in the editor after selecting the language from the syntax drop-down menu.

For example: 
After selecting HTML, I want the editor to immediately add, for example, `<!doctype html> <head> <body> <title>`, et cetera, et cetera.

Is there a way for me to do this, or do I need to download/add certain plugins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The emmet plugin might do its job.

Comment: Thank you, this was what i needed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with a simple plugin. You can listen for when the syntax is changed to HTML, check the file is otherwise empty, and if so, insert the HTML snippet.

1. Tools menu -> Developer -> New Plugin...
2. Replace the template with the following code:

```py
import sublime
import sublime_plugin


class SyntaxChangeListener(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
    def on_post_text_command(self, view, command_name, args):
        if view.size() > 0:
            return

        if command_name == 'set_file_type':
            if args['syntax'] == 'Packages/HTML/HTML.sublime-syntax':
                view.run_command('insert_snippet', { 'name': 'Packages/HTML/Snippets/html.sublime-snippet' })
```

3. Save it, in the folder ST recommends (`Packages/User`) as something like `insert_html_snippet_for_new_files.py` - the name itself doesn't matter, as long as the file extension is `py`.
4. Open a new tab
5. Set the syntax to HTML
6. See the HTML snippet get automatically inserted