# Any way in SublimeText 4 to include a path for a file type?

Tags: javascript, typescript, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin, sublimetext4

I want to include a global file path, specifically "C:\dev-tools\node_modules@types\jquery\index.d.ts" every time a JS file is being edited. Any way to do this?

I can see in this question/answer that a custom plugin can be coded to automatically insert snippets based on file type, can something similar be done but just include a path?

[Is there a way in Sublime text 3 to auto add the format for language after selecting it from syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69767931/is-there-a-way-in-sublime-text-3-to-auto-add-the-format-for-language-after-selec/69774295#69774295?newreg=fbf4db09826a43cea18274eb86d8c1b7)

Trying to get autocomplete for jQuery for files that are not part of a project.

Thanks in advance.

I have tried adding the file by reference like so:

`/// <reference path="C:\dev-tools\node_modules\@types\jquery\index.d.ts" />`

And this works (I have LSP and LSP-typescript installed) and autocomplete works flawlessly. I also have jquery types globally installed so adding this to the beginning of the file works too:

`require(jQuery);`

**I am trying to achieve/expecting to achieve**

...being able to get autocomplete without extra code in the beginning of the file which I'd have to remove later on.

Answer (score 0):

You can include the path to jQuery as part of your `.sublime-project` file. Just select **`Project → Add Folder to Project…`** and select `C:\dev-tools\node_modules\@types\jquery`, and it will be indexed for autocomplete along with all the other folders.